# Python plugins like Minecraft Bukkit

Tags: python, plugins

I've been reading this:
http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/writing-a-python-plugin-api/

I'm trying to do something like Minecraft help system.
Let's say I have my main module, and the help commands are:

> help
>   test1
>   test2

And then, after loading the plugin, I would have the same set, plus the ones that the plugin has available.
Also, when processing the commands, how can I do, to distinguish the ones from internal program to the ones from plugins?!
So far, I've come up with this:

```
import imp
import os

PluginFolder = "./plugins"
MainModule = "__init__"

def getPlugins():
    plugins = []
    possibleplugins = os.listdir(PluginFolder)
    for i in possibleplugins:
        location = os.path.join(PluginFolder,i)
        if not os.path.isdir(location) or not MainModule + ".py" in os.listdir(location):
            continue
        info = imp.find_module(MainModule, [location])
        plugins.append({"name":i, "info": info})
    return plugins

def loadPlugin(plugin):
    return imp.load_module(MainModule, *plugin["info"])

disponiveis = []
for i in getPlugins():
    print("Loading plugin "+ i["name"])
    plugin = loadPlugin(i)
    plugin.run()
    disponiveis.append(i["name"])

while 1:
    foo = raw_input(":")
    if foo == 'quit':
        break;
    elif foo in disponiveis:
        print "ok"
    else:
        continue
```

Not much from the original example :|
My BIG problem is that cycle where it loads all the plugins.
Currently I have 2 plugins, *hello* and *testing*. How can I do to have something like this:

```
send_command(plugin_name, action)
```

Also, the if/elif is kinda lame... Available commands should come from the plugin.
Using a *dict* maybe?!?! And then when loading the plugin, it would add the aditional commands to that dict ?!?!

Comment: what's the structure of your plugin? Is it a class, method, are you passing anything to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers and help, but I shouldn't try to re-invent the wheel.
This framework is great:
http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/

Works like a charm.
(It did help to learn more about Python)

Answer (score 3):

As the last line of the blog entry you cite says "Now, of course, this plugin API is very simple, and can easily (and should) be extended for your program’s needs."

The only "api" defined in the sample code is a `plugin.run()` method that doesn't return anything. So at the very least from your question it sounds like you need one the describes the available "commands" the loaded plugin has. One way to do that would be to define another method that all plugins must provide called `available_commands()` which returns a dictionary of commands where the keys are all command names and the values are corresponding functions that do them.

However that could need to be extended with some mechanism to provide command argument information back to the client application as well. How this might be done is limited only by your imagination to either invent something yourself or perhaps learn how others have done it, perhaps by asking a more specific question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: The owner of the blog posted a sample, but the only way to make it work is by always loading the module anytime that the command is used :|

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you, but it seems reasonable to me to expect to have to load a plugin before you can execute one of its commands...or even ask it what commands it understands. There's no way for the main application to know anything about it otherwise, since they were written at different times, at least in theory.

Comment: nevermind the comment, I was missing some things at the code.
I'll post it later.